# Turn on CRON jobs, many months after published webshop. What happens?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, order-email

I have taken over the responsibility for a web shop. This Magento shop has not activated the CRON jobs. Meaning all purchases has not been sent out the emails and all that related CRON jobs stuff at all since the beginning.

I was just about to activate cron jobs, but does this mean a lot of people are going to get tons of emails now, months after their purchase?

Can I clear everything before activating the cron job?

Comment: I had this recently doing an upgrade and yeah sent out like a few hundred emails from an abandoned cart plugin... you could in theory edit the data to make it appear that it has been sent already but that'd be a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the table core_email_queue.

All mails, that should have been sent out by the cronjob, should be inside this table.